# Ordinals in category theory?

Tags: category-theory, ordinals

I am just learning category theory and I am wondering if there is some way to define ordinals, and ordinal arithmetic purely through categorical means. I have a notion of taking a category with 0, 1, 2, etc elements but I have no idea how you could define addition on these categories with the usual nice properties (associativity, commutativity in the finite case, etc). I also don't know how this would generalize to categories representing ordinals $\geq \omega$.

Through the basic notions of category theory, what is an ordinal? And what does ordinal arithmetic look like categorically?

Comment: Ordinals are partial orders and so in particular are themselves categories. It's surprisingly unclear what ordinal arithmetic looks like in this setup.

Comment: Ah, no, it's fine, ordinal sum is join: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/join+of+categories

Comment: Do you want to see ordinals as categories (as Qiaochu Yuan proposes) and reflect ordinal arithmetic at that level, or do you want to define cardinals internally to a fixed category with sufficient structure?

Comment: @Pece Whichever is more natural, or perhaps both. I just want ordinals defined from a categorical point of view.

Comment: I wouldn't be optimistic about the internal version then. Suppose you have defined $\mathbf n$ as some avatar of the finite ordinals $n$ inside a given category for each $n\in \mathbb N$. It should come with maps $\mathbf n \to \mathbf {n+1}$ and the only sensitive definition of $\boldsymbol\omega$ is the transfinite composition... which is only defined up to iso. This is a no-go if you want to get back the usual ordinals in $\mathbf{Set}$.

Comment: @Pece I don't understand your point. The ordinals will have to be defined as internal posets, and so $\omega$ will have to be defined up to isomorphism of posets. I see no issue with that.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Yes you are right, I didn't thought about making them internal posets directly, I was just wondering what would happen if we were to mimic the usual construction of ordinals in, say, a topos and I stumble across the "increasing union" not being so good then. I guess taking the transfinite composition in the category of internal posets would yield a well-behaved $\omega$ then.

Comment: Is there any particular reason to focus on *ordinal numbers*, rather than just working with well-ordered sets? IMO, ordinal numbers are solutions to problems that category theorists don't face: category theorists don't usually need to single out canonical representatives from isomorphisms classes, and even when they do, they rarely need specific constructions; and ordinal numbers are a way for set theorists to relate well-order types to $\in$, but orderings already fit seamlessly into category theory so no extra effort is required in that direction.

Answer (score 7):

The class $\bf Ord$ of ordinal numbers can be described as the free algebra on a singleton, with respect to a certain monad $P$ on the category of classes (although not precisely a $P$-algebra).

The [reference](http://www.numdam.org/article/DIA_1979__2__A5_0.pdf) is this old paper by Rosicky.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in the concept of a [natural numbers object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_numbers_object) in a category. I find this to be a beautifully simple idea - it basically implements the concept of zero and a successor function. If you're working in a category like Set where such an object exists, you can think about things like iterating a function $n$ times.